# I'm using Scala 2.11.7 but sbt tries to compile my classes to target/scala-2.10

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to get a simple ScalatraServlet running.

When I compile I can see that it fails to import any of my Scalatra componenents. Strangely enough, it's trying to compile to a directory called **scala-2.10/classes**, even though I'm using Scala 2.11.

What's going wrong with my project?

```
sal@gruntyman:~/workspace/funproxy$ sbt compile
[info] Loading project definition from /home/sal/workspace/funproxy/project
[info] Set current project to funproxy (in build file:/home/sal/workspace/funproxy/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/sal/workspace/funproxy/}funproxy...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to /home/sal/workspace/funproxy/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/sal/workspace/funproxy/src/main/scala/ProxyServlet.scala:5: object scalatra is not a member of package org
[error] import org.scalatra.ScalatraServlet
[error]            ^
[error] /home/sal/workspace/funproxy/src/main/scala/ProxyServlet.scala:7: not found: type ScalatraServlet
[error] class ProxyServlet extends ScalatraServlet with ScalateSupport {
[error]                            ^
[error] /home/sal/workspace/funproxy/src/main/scala/ProxyServlet.scala:7: not found: type ScalateSupport
[error] class ProxyServlet extends ScalatraServlet with ScalateSupport {
[error]                                                 ^
[error] /home/sal/workspace/funproxy/src/main/scala/ProxyServlet.scala:11: not found: value get
[error]   get("/") {
[error]   ^
[error] four errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 31-Jan-2016 14:23:46
sal@gruntyman:~/workspace/funproxy$ sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.7
```

This is my SBT config:

```
name := "funproxy"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

lazy val scalatraVersion = "2.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.14"
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.5" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % scalatraVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % scalatraVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % scalatraVersion % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.2.10.v20150310" % "runtime"
//libraryDependencies +=  "ch.qos.logback"    %  "logback-classic"   % "1.1.3"            % "runtime"
//libraryDependencies += "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.2"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature")
```

Comment: What is "my SBT config". Is that a file named `build.sbt` in your project's root folder? Because if not, sbt will not pick it up. The scalatra-not-found error hints at this, too. You can easily find out by running `sbt` without arguments, and on the sbt console execute `show name`, `show version`, `show scalaVersion`.

Comment: OK, it was called build.sbt but it was in project/ - moved now, and that seemed to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sbt finds build files only if they are in simple `.sbt` format *within the project's root directory*, or if they are in full `.scala` format *in the sub-directory `project`*. If you place an `.sbt` file inside the `project` sub-directory, that will be for the meta-project, e.g. containing plugin definitions.